# SOAP PHP problem

Tags: php, soap

can any one help me in developing soap client whereas parameters type of soap server's functions is object etc.

```
$client->__call("functionName",array(/*now how to find parameter type if they are object*/));
```

thanks ...

Answer (score 1):

Just read the official documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php). There are plenty of examples, you only have to copy, paste and adapt them.

Comment: basically its object oriented, no as simple as it look like

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't know how to use SOAP in PHP then try to use a WSDL to PHP generator such as [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator). With this is you'll have a PHP SDK corresponding to SOAP Web Service using the native PHP SoapClient class. A tutorial file is also generated that can be used as a starting guide.